# How to avoid passwords when switching from root to another user

Tags: sudo

I login as user1(with password) then switch to root user (with password), but to run my script i need to be user3 which doesn't require password (su user3).

when am using sudo it errors out as :

Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  /bin/bash -l -c "su user3 -c '/home/setupEnv.py'"

Please any solutions?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:' /bin/bash -l -c "su user3 -c '/home/setupEnv.py'"Aborting.
Disconnecting from host

Comment: This does not look like an error message.

Comment: @techmind, this looks more like a message indicating success of your command.

Comment: What I can understand is, its trying to take sudo password already passed as env.password , which is not required. How to avoid this

Comment: Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: su user3 -c '/home/setupEnv.py'
Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  /bin/bash -l -c "su user3 -c '/home/setupEnv.py'"